# yyparse is printing a leading tab

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

In my bison/flex program, right after yyparse() is called, a leading tab is printed, but I don't know why. Can you see what's wrong?

This calls the bison code, and right after yyparse() returns, a tab is printed.

```
void parseArguments(int argc, char** argv)
130 {
131     int i;
132 
133     int sum = 0;
134     // calculate the length of buffer we need
135     for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
136     {
137         sum += strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
138     }
139 
140     if(sum <= 0)
141         return;
142 
143     // make us a buffer and zero it out
144     char tempBuffer[sum];
145     memset(tempBuffer, 0, sum);
146 
147     // pointer to walk through our buffer
148     int pos = 0;
149 
150     // copy arguments into the buffer
151     for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
152     {
153         memcpy(tempBuffer+pos, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
154         pos += strlen(argv[i]);
155         sprintf(tempBuffer+pos++, " ");
156     }
157 
158     // give our arguments to lex for parsing
159     configBuffer(tempBuffer);
160 


// use bison parsing
163     int returnVal = yyparse(); // after this returns a tab character has been printed


164     if(returnVal != 0)                                                                                            
   165     {   
   166         printf("yyparse failed!\n");                                                                              
   167     }                                                                                                             
   168
```

All my bison rules are just regular expressions paired with a return statement. The only code of interest in bison that I could see affecting this would be this:

```
64 %%
 65 void configBuffer(char* arguments)
 66 {
 67 #ifdef DEBUG
 68     printf("Given the buffer: %s\n", arguments);
 69 #endif
 70     yy_delete_buffer(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER);
 71 
 72     yy_scan_string(arguments);
 73 }
```

I tried the suggestions given by several people, but still not luck. Here is my full flex file:

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include "CommandParser.tab.h"
%}

%%

\t {
    printf("TAB!\n");
}

" " {
    printf("SPACE!\n");
}

\n {
    return;
}

-p {
    return PRINTMODE; 
}

-x {
    return XORMODE;
}

-n {
    return NOTMODE;
}

-a {
    return ANDMODE;
}

-o {
    return ORMODE;
}

-r {
    return RANGEFLAG;
}

-l {
    return LENGTHFLAG;
}

0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+ {
    int retVal = sscanf(yytext, "%x",&(yylval.int_val));
    if(retVal != 1)
        return;
    return NUMBER;
}

[0-9]+ {
    yylval.int_val = atoi(yytext);
    return NUMBER;
}

['"].*+['"] {
    yylval.string_val = strdup(yytext);
    return ARGUMENT;
}

[^ \t\n]+ {
    yylval.string_val = strdup(yytext);
    return ARGUMENT;
}


%%
void configBuffer(char* arguments)
{
#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Given the buffer: %s:\n", arguments);
#endif
    yy_delete_buffer(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER);
    yy_scan_string(arguments);
```

}

Comment: Seeing your lex code might be helpful to try and figure out if you're tokenizing correctly.  If you're trying to ignore white space, have you added in the appropriate rule for the RegEx [ \t\n]?  (You can throw \r into that too if you need to.)

A bit more information could help in solving this problem.

Comment: how it this issue proceeding?

Comment: Turned out that the ['"].*+['"] rule was making the program unhappy. I rewrote my other rule for ARGUMENT(s) and deleted that rule, and everything ended up working out fine. Still not too sure why though...

Comment: that rule is quite odd, you match a single quote or a double quote ['"] then match any non-newline character zero or more times .* but then match the previous rule one or more times + this I think is your mistake, then the first part again ['"] I wonder if you removed the + or * you might get a better result. Also I assume you would want to have a negative match in the middle section, as .* is a greedy match. So I would tend to have two matches for the single and double quote case like '[^']*' and "[^"]*"

Comment: Well regardless, I was able to resolve it by just deleting the rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the tab not handled in you lexer and therefore the default rule matching and echoed is being applied?

Put a extra match

```
\t { printf("TAB"); }
```

into the code before your end code section.

if that shows TAB instead of the \t, then turn the printf into an empty statement

```
\t { /*printf("TAB")*/; }
```

**After lex posting Edit:**

Ok, after testing your lex it would seem you are matching things correctly.

I used this code to test it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CommandParser.tab.h"

YYSTYPE yylval;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("lex:%d\r\n",yylex());
    }
    return 0;
}

extern "C" int yywrap();

int yywrap ()
{
    return 1;
}
```

So with the input (via stdin)

```
-a<\ >-x<\t>-p<space>-c<\r>
```

I get

```
lex:103
SPACE!
lex:101
TAB!
lex:100
SPACE!
lex:108
lex:3
```

for this header file

```
#define PRINTMODE   100
#define XORMODE     101
#define NOTMODE     102
#define ANDMODE     103
#define ORMODE      104
#define LENGTHFLAG  105
#define RANGEFLAG   106
#define NUMBER      107
#define ARGUMENT    108
#define DEFUALT     0

typedef union {
    int int_val;
    char* string_val;
} YYSTYPE;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" int yylex();

extern "C" YYSTYPE yylval;
#else // __cplusplus
extern YYSTYPE yylval;
#endif // __cplusplus
```

So what I'd try next is replace the `yyparse` with this code and see what you get.

```
while(1)
{
    printf("lex:%d\r\n",yylex());
}
```

If you still get the tab printed it is somehow you lexer, otherwise it is somehow your parser/main program.

To find that out I'd replace the magic string building you do with a `const string`, and see what happen in that case. Basically binary search your code to find the problem spot.